# How to prefetch correctly a CSS file?

Tags: html, w3c-validation, prefetch

I use two CSS files, one is a little one for my `home.html` with all the important things for this page and there I pre fetch a bigger CSS file that takes care of the internal structure.

It works as I want but when I try to pass the W3C validation it complains with:

> Error: A `link` element with an `as` attribute must have a `rel` attribute
>   that contains the value `preload`.
>
> ```
> <link rel="prefetch alternate stylesheet" href="/css/internal.css" as="style">
> ```

Can I get rid correctly of this?

Comment: Either change it to `rel="preload alternate stylesheet"` (`preload` instead of `prefetch`) or drop `as="style"`